# Integrals of two modified Bessel functions of the second kind with respect to the order

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

I've been trying to calculate this Kontorovich-Lebedev transform which involves an integral with a product of two modified Bessel functions of the second kind with respect to their order. Does anyone know how to go about doing these?

$$
\int_0^\infty K_{i\xi}(x_1) K_{i\xi}(x_2) \sinh(\pi\xi)\cos(a\xi)\coth(b \xi)\mathrm{d}\xi
$$
$a$ is real, $b,~x_1$, and $x_2$ are strictly positive.

Comment: This integral involves four parameters and five functions, two of which are special. When it comes to finding a closed form, all I can say is *good luck*.

Comment: You may try to substitute http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E18 and convert it into a double integral involving only one modified Bessel function.

Comment: That was a good idea, and I did try that! However, when I interchange the order of the two integrals the integral over $\xi$ no longer converges. This is because, asymptotically, $K_{i\xi}\sim O(e^{-\pi\xi/2}/\sqrt{\xi})$ so two of them can handle my $\sinh(\pi\xi)$ but with just one the integral grows exponentially.